# Is it legal to display ads in an iPhone app without using Apple's iAd system

Tags: ios, iad

Is it legal to display ads in an iPhone app without using Apple's iAd advertising system? Is it still legal if I am compensated for displaying those ads?

I have asked on the official Apple forums but have not gotten a good answer.

Thanks!

Comment: do you mean is it legal to put ads from other services in your iphone app,and earn money from them?

Comment: Have you signed up with Apple with a developer agreement so that you can submit apps to the app store etc.? If so then read the contract Apple sent you. Alternatively ask Apple.

Comment: I very much doubt that Apple will let you do this. They want you to use their ad service.

Comment: Hi all. I think i didn't saw it because i have not activated iAD agreement yet. I will do it and check this legal question :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is perfectly legal. Lots of apps on the app store use ad providers such as AdMob etc. but the reason that iAds are most often used is that they get the most revenue on average.